# Permission needed for manage permission set users

Tags: profile, permission-sets

what are the Permissions needed for a user to be able to assign/manage users in a permission set? And where those permissions are? at user level or profile level?
[image: Not able to find Assign Permission set]

Comment: You might want to look at delegated administration if you want to control which permission sets a user can assign. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_delegate.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

There are two permissions to assign/manage permissions set.
There permissions are found under Administrative Permissions section of a Profile.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i'm not able to locate the permission in my profile. My profile is having salesforce platform license. I've attached the screenshot of Administrative Permissions section of my Profile.

Comment: Seems, profiles with Salesforce Platform user licenses does not have these permission. You can create a Permission Set to hold these permission and can assign this permission set to User. I have taken the screenshot from System Administrator Profile whih has Salesforce user license.

Comment: I've tried to do the same. But the problem is that you can assign a Persmission set with Salesforce user license to a profile with the same user license not to a profile with Salesforce Platform user license. And in the Permission Set for Salesforce Platform user license these two permissions are still unavailable same as its profile.

Comment: @user59759 Yes, you are right. The "Salesforce Platform" user license doesn't allow the permission: Manage Profiles and Permission Sets. A profile should be of "Salesforce" license to work on the Permission Sets.